# Django - send email when object is created

Tags: django

Generally, in order to send an email when an object is created, I would override the save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    send_email(context)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I now need the context to contain an attribute of the object that cannot be known until the object is saved, namely the url of a File object associated with the model object.

I am aware that this can be done with post_save signal, but the docs give the impression that this is best used when disparate models need access to such information. I get the impression that it's not good practice to use it in a single-model setup like this.

I've tried this:

```
    foo = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    send_email(foo.document.url)
    return foo
```

But `foo` seems to be `None`.

Comment: Your best bet to this is to create a ‘post_save’ signal as you said, and check ‘if created:’.

Comment: Don't you need `self.document.url`? `foo` is just the result of the `save` call.

Comment: @squaregoldfish Oh, yes, sorry, but presumably self will refer to the class, not the actual object. I was hoping that super().save(...) might return the created object, but apparently not...

Answer (score 1):

The save method doesn't return anything. But the item is `self`, you can use that after calling super.

```
super().save(*args, **kwargs)
send_email(self.document.url)
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Would you recommend this over signals?

Comment: It doesn't really make much difference. I'm not generally a huge fan of Python signals though.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is correct, but if you only want to send the email when the object is created, not if it's updated, you should also check if the instance has a pk assigned, for example:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    created = self.pk is None
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if created:
        send_email(context)
```